# Cannot install php, apache and postgres on ubuntu base image in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I started studying docker recently and wanted to install php, apache and postgres in a ubuntu base image. But cannot run it after build.

Here is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04


RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0
RUN apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php7.0
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-mysql
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-pgsql
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-gd
RUN apt-get -y install php-pear
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-curl

COPY . /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Typically you'd run this in two or three separate containers; the [standard `php` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) includes a `...-apache` variant that bundles the PHP interpreter and Apache together, but you'd still need a separate database container.

Comment: I know I should run this in separate containers and I'll do it later. First I want try all in one.
Also I did some experiment with ```php:apache``` as a base image. Now I am trying to install php, apache, postgres on ubuntu base image.

Answer (score 0):

there are several issues here. First of all, I have the impression that you're mixing up docker and virtual machines. For this I suggest to go and read what are the differences.

Concerning your question, the problem is that the base image (ubuntu:16.04) has `CMD bash` (or something similar, I really didn't check) and therefore php is not considered.

In order to start apache, you should append the following:

```
CMD . /etc/apache2/envvars && /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
```

Anyway, I'd suggest you give a check to the [php](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) official image.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! But this command shows Apache2 ubuntu default page. I have a ```index.php``` page in the same directory of the docker and cannot show that. Can you help me a little more?

Comment: well, you need to setup apache. My knowledge concerning this topic is pretty stale, so I suggest some basic googling about setting up apache2 and php7 on ubuntu.